# How to connect to the administrator account when arriving at the logging screen?

Tags: windows-7, windows

There is a computer of our coworker running `Windows7` which when booted then has password when arrived on the logging screen. It is not the administrator user. I want to log as the administrator account. How to make that ? Is there a key combination for that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always use the "switch user" option after logging in to the station. It should be available somewhere in the "shut down" menus

Comment: the problem is that the user is not connected ! the desktop is not yet opened !

Comment: how about ctrl+alt+del ?

Comment: I will try that later because the person is here :) lol

Comment: ctrl+alt+del does not work !

Comment: can you post the picture of the display with the login screen ?
ctrl+alt+del
should pop up the login screen on any windows system, and in the login screen it should allow you to change the user (never tested with only one user though - there are almost alywas at least 2 on a fresh install)

Answer (score 0):

Keep the SHIFT key down while the logon screen comes up. But be warned: the 'disable autologin bypass' procedure can be prohibited by a setting in the registry.

Comment: it does not work !

Comment: I understood that the user is logged in automatically "then has password" is not very precise. If you are only getting to the password prompt, then Ctrl+Alt+Del should bring a menu up which allows you to "change user". AFAIK the Administrator account is disabled by default so this may not work for you.